# Edit links in header.phtml block

Tags: magento-1.8, header, toplinks, topmenu, page-layouts

I need to alter the Blog url in the "The Checkout | Blog | Login/Register" block that is referenced in the

```
theme/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

I have looked everywhere and cannot find it. All I need to do is change the **http** to **https** for the blog link which was a customisation put in by my ex-developer

In the `/header.phtml`, this is part of the code that calls it, but I can't find where I can edit either the topContainer or topMenu. I iave looked in most/layout .xml's as well and cannot find anything there.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
 <div id="nav-top">
    <div class="container">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
    </div>
 </div>
```

IT is driving me mental!

Comment: is there any extension check layout file in that layout they mention

Comment: Im not sure what you mean sorry!

Comment: Is it any Extension or you custom code

Comment: I am fairly sure it was code that was customised by my old developer, but I cant find any evidence of it in any of the page/html files

Comment: I found it in wordpress.xml, but but I need to change the link to https from http, but I cant do it from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your

```
app\design\frontend\theme\default\layout\page.xml
```

May be you will find under

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
```

if still not able to find then search the Keyword "Blog" in your project, to search in whole project clone the project in your local machine and search using NetBans in whole project or any other editor which you have installed.

Comment: thanks, but it is not in app\design\frontend\theme\default\layout\page.xml  I did download NetBans but I have no idea how to use it or get it set up it looks really complicated?

Comment: I have just done a search via windows of the files, and found this in wordpress.xml <reference name="top.links">
   <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="wordpress" ifconfig="wordpress/toplink/enabled">
    <label helper="wordpress/getTopLinkLabel" />
    <url helper="wordpress/getTopLinkUrl"/>
    <title>Blog</title>
    <prepare>0</prepare>
    <urlParams />
    <position helper="wordpress/getTopLinkPosition" />
    <li_params />
    <a_params>class="top-link-blog"</a_params>
   </action>
  </reference>    but I still cant change the URL to https instead of http

Comment: **In app\code\community\Fishpig\Wordpress\Helper\Data.php around line 25**


Replace : <br/>

`$transport = new Varien_Object(array('toplink_url' => $this->getUrl()));`

To:

`transport = new Varien_Object(array('toplink_url' => $this->getUrl('', array('_secure' => true))));`

after this clear your cache and try

Note: File path may change in your environment if you modified the extension files

Comment: Is it worked for you?